# Brain MRI Segmentation Using FCM (Labeling)

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, imaging, fuzzy-c-means

I am doing Brain MRI segmentation using Fuzzy C-Means, The volume image is n slices, and I apply the FCM for each slice, the output is 4 labels per image (Gray Matter, White Matter, CSF and the background), how I can give the same label (Color) for each material for all the slices) I am using matlab

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you apply the clustering to all voxels from all slices at once? – If this doesn't address your problem, you need to explain more precisely what you are trying to achieve, what you tried to do, and where you got stuck.

Comment: I am trying to segment Brain MRI volume image into 3 clusters (White matter, Gray Matter, and CSF), I tried to do what you said (To segment the whole volume) but I got error in the reshape function as follow:- Error using label2rgb
Expected input number 1, L, to be two-dimensional. The code is shown in the main question above

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to run the code, but my guess is: Line 12 should say `numel(data)` instead of `length(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your FCM function is working correctly it should output the same 4 label values for each slice, for example `[0 1 2 3]`. Really this is a display issue and has nothing to do with the actual segmentation. If the labels are being output as different values that is another problem. This can be accomplished with `label2rgb` as the documentation suggests [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/label2rgb.html). I would probably use this form:

```
RGB = label2rgb(L, map)
```

Where map is a [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html). If you pass the same `map` to each slice's call to `label2rgb` the labels will be returned with the same colors. This can also be implemented relatively easily. Assume your labels are `[0,1,2,3]` and you have a variable `labels` with your label image, and you could do:

```
% //define your own custom colormap to be whatever you like
cmap = [1 1 1; ...% //white
        1 0 0; ...% //red
        0 1 0; ...% //green
        0 0 1];   % //blue
 labelVisSlice = zeros(size(labels,1),size(labels,2),3); % //make mxnx3 array
 tmp1=labelVisSlice(:,:,1);
 tmp2=labelVisSlice(:,:,2);
 tmp3=labelVisSlice(:,:,3);
 % //now loop over all the labels and fill in the colors. 
 for label=1:length(unique(labels))
    labeledVoxels = labels==label;
    % //I'm sure there is a much faster way to do this but It's not coming to mind
    tmp1(labeledVoxels)=cmap(label+1,1);
    tmp2(labeledVoxels)=cmap(label+1,2);
    tmp3(labeledVoxels)=cmap(label+1,3);
 end
 labelVisSlice=cat(3,tmp1,tmp2,tmp3);
 imagesc(labelVisSlice);
```